# Is it safe to leave a Sheltie puppy with access to a doggy door?

Tags: containment, outdoor

I have to go to work during the day and I'm struggling to find a system that works well for making my Sheltie comfortable when I'm gone. I leave her in the house with plenty of food and water, check on her during my lunch break if I can, etc, but potty training is **NOT** going well.

So, what I'd like to do is install a doggy door this weekend. That way she'd have a lot more space to play in and it would make it infinitely easier to potty train her. Asides from the fact that I find training pads to be gross, she doesn't get what they're for anyway, despite my many attempts to follow tutorials on training her.

She likes to go outside ("go" in both senses of the word). So that's great.

But there's 1 problem. While my yard **is** fully fenced, at 3 months she's still skinny enough to squeeze between the gaps in my fence when she wants to. This is kind of what the fence looks like (more or less):

[image: main fence]

My plan is to add a 2nd level of fencing, probably using the thick plastic net with metal stakes you see here:

[image: safety fencing]

However, I'm fearful that she'll be able to dig under or bite through it. Is that a valid concern with this kind of puppy?

If she can chew through it, suppose I put in metal chicken wire. Would that do the trick or would she dig under it? I've never seen her digging but I used to have a husky so I know that some dogs would dig under it in seconds.

Comment: Have you considered the likelihood of dog theft?  A small desirable -looking puppy is exactly the sort of dog that someone is likely to scoop out of your garden.    I don't think anyone can answer the 'will dog pup chew through plastic net' question without trying it - it's really down to personality - but I'd be reluctant to take the risk myself unless the area outside the fence is also pretty safe.

Comment: @Victoria To be honest, no I had never considered that. I didn't think that people stole dogs. I will have to think about that. She's got a GPS tracker and a microchip and I do have security cameras, but I suppose they could take off the tracker and cameras aren't fool proof. As far as the fence I'm just thinking to get something that a puppy can't chew thru even if she tries. I suppose chicken wire would be the better choice.

Comment: Have you considered a dog run and just leave the dog outside during the day.

Comment: @Paparazzi What do you mean, like take her for a walk? Yea, I try to do that once a day though she is still learning to walk on a leash. I would just  leave her outside but I am concerned about the heat / rain and the lady in the comment above mentioned that people are apparently stealing puppies out of your yard...

Comment: Dog run is a noun where I live

Comment: @Paparazzi Oh, ok. Yea I had never heard of that but I did some Google searches and determined that you mean one of those big outdoor cages. I was thinking about it, but her breed has a lot of hair, she's young, it's hot outside, etc, etc.

Comment: People will steal anything that's worth money.
https://www.paws.org/get-involved/animal-cruelty/pet-theft/
http://www.akc.org/press-center/pet-theft/